# C# WinForms messed up control positions?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have this running software that is currently being used by about 400 people. To most of them (and to me) it all looks fine and dandy, but a couple of users have reported the controls looking weird, all messed-up, position-like...

Do you guys know any errors that may be preventing this from working correctly or any solutions?

EDIT: http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6707/capturarvw.png

Comment: No idea.  Does your app take DPI into account?  In Windows 7 the default DPI setting has changed.

Comment: You need to collect more information about the differences of the environments for the users that are having problems, such as .NET version, OS version, display resolution, etc.

Comment: One that I know of is using it in an Iconia Windows tablet, with a 800x1280 resolution. I'm trying to get the most data I can from them, but no success so far. No idea how to work with different DPI, though...

Comment: I've seen a lot of WinForms weirdness come up when users run their Windows in classic mode i.e. Windows 2000 look and feel. Make sure to ask about that in addition to @mellamokb's good suggestions.

Comment: I've been able to simulate the problem locally by changing the DPI to 125%. Now... how to fix that? Is there a way to make it work in different DPI settings? What the user DPI is already set to default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i Make my WinForms Application DPI-Aware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296810/how-can-i-make-my-winforms-application-dpi-aware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form’s `AutoScaleMode` from `Font` to `None`, and the form won’t respond to DPI changes.

Of course it would be best if you could instead scale properly. Can’t wait till everyone’s using frameworks that make it hard *not* to do this. Like WPF.

Comment: That is not a complete fix, though it may alleviate some issues. The problem has to do with specifying coordinates in pixels instead of relative to something else.

Comment: I am having this issue as well, where my main System.Windows.Forms.Form has AutoScaleMode set to Font. Changing it to either Inherit or None resolve the munged layout issue on a Win7 box.
With regards to Ed S. comment above, how do you specify coordinates in anything OTHER than pixels if there is a larger issue to resolve here?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever encounter such problem again, the basic rule is to get as much information from your customers as possible. You need to collect their version of Windows, .NET, resolution etc. If you could get this info, it's MUCH easier (and faster) to narrow down the problem and eliminate it.

As few people before me suggested, this may be caused by several issues. My personal guess would be badly implemented layout... Maybe try to post some code, so we can see it, and definitely get more info from your unhappy customers.